# Minicart is not displaying quantity of preadded products after login

Tags: magento-2.0.2

products are displaying after login on cart page but there quantity is not displaying at minicart after login. but if I add new product or remove old product than quantity is updating in minicart. Is anyone have any solution for this problem in magento2 ?